# why use .ejs.html instead of just .ejs?

Tags: javascript, html, web, ejs

I am contributing to an open-source project and it seems that all of the website's pages have .ejs.html format.
what is the difference between these two formats ?
ejs is used to embed javascript inside html code.why use .ejs.html instead of just html.

Comment: It would be better to ask this question to your co-contributors. You can call a CSV file `file.csv`, `file.txt`, or `file.my_awesome_format`; in the ideal world the extension gives a hint about the format of the contents, but for all we know your `.ejs.html` could be HTML files that describe how to use EJS, or they could be a misnamed MS Word documents. They could be named `.ejs.html` because they are HTML files with EJS templating, but the editor that the person who created those files uses does not have syntax highlighting for the `.ejs` extension. Only they know the true reason.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Comment: There are some related questions on Webmasters that may point you in the right direction even if they don't answer your question exactly: [Should I use a file extension or not?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/should-i-use-a-file-extension-or-not) and [Why are extensions often hidden on URLs?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/48271/why-are-extensions-often-hidden-on-urls)